# Sequelize Query - Finding records based on many-to-many table and parent table

Tags: many-to-many, sequelize.js

Given the following sequelize models:

```
var User = db.define('user', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING
});


var Group = db.define('group', {
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  public : { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, defaultValue: true }
});

Group.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'specialUsers', through: 'user_groups', foreignKey: 'group_id' });


User.belongsToMany(Group, { through: 'user_groups', foreignKey: 'user_id' });
```

How would I go about finding the Groups for a through the Groups model where the Groups returned should be those where the user has a record in the many to many table -- or -- the group is a public group?

I've tried something like this:

```
return Group.findAll({
  attributes: ['name', 'public'],
  include: [{
    model: User,
    as: 'specialUsers',
    where: {
      $or : [
        {name: 'Neill'},
        Sequelize.literal('"group"."public" = true')
      ]
    }
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Group.findAll({
  attributes: ['name', 'public'],
  include: [{
    model: User,
    as: 'specialUsers',
  }],
  where: {
    $or : {
      '$users.name$": 'Neill',
      public: true
    }
  }
});
```

Should work if you are on a fairly recent version. Note that I moved the where out of the include

Comment: thanks but doesn't seem to work, the include results in an inner join (I think)-- which filters out groups which do not have related records in the user_groups table.. any other ideas?

Comment: Actually-- I think that might have worked--- let me double check.. thanks!